# Restricting field input for android devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a name field that only allows the user to enter Alphabetical characters.
I have used multiple methods of preventing invalid characters including regular expressions and JavaScript events. This needs to work for both computers and mobile devices. But for Android devices specifically, there seems to be an issue (I believe the OS overrides or doesn't play well with code intended for PCs). What is the best way to only allow alphabetical characters on all devices?

Here is how I am doing it now.

Html

```
<input runat="server" class="form-control restrictNameInput" id="firstName" name="firstName" maxlength="50" type="text" required />
```

JS

```
$("input.restrictNameInput").keypress(restrictNameInput);//prevents on keypress, works on computers.

//This is a catch all that goes back and strips invalid characters:
$("input.restrictNameInput").on('keydown keyup keypress change blur focus focusin focusout paste', function () {
    var stripped = $(this).val().replace(/[^\-\'a-zA-Z ]+/i, '');
    $(this).val(stripped);
});

function restrictNameInput(e) {
    if (!((e.which > 64 && e.which < 91) || (e.which > 96 && e.which < 123) || e.which == 32 || e.which == 39 || e.which == 45)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really consider adding multiple event listeners at once instead of repeating code: `.on('keydown keyup keypress change blur focus focusin focusout paste', function () {`

Comment: To be honest, rather than stripping the user input, it would be more elegant to supply an error message as soon as an invalid char is detected and keep the error visible until all illegal chars have been fixed.

Comment: It's actually a form with many fields and I don't want to use error messages on the name fields. It's just frustrating that the other devices I have tested prevent illegal characters fine, but only on Android devices, it doesn't work very well.

Comment: Did you try my first suggestion? What is the purpose of `keypress`-> `restrictNameInput()`? It looks like it's interfering for no reason.

Comment: You should be aware that different browsers handle events slightly differently. Years ago I encountered a Firefox event listener discrepancy which drove me absolutely nuts until I binded more events.

Comment: Yes @MonkeyZeus $("input.restrictNameInput").on('keydown keyup keypress change blur focus focusin focusout paste', function () {
        var stripped = $(this).val().replace(/[^\-\'a-zA-Z ]+/i, '');
        $(this).val(stripped);
    });
worked! Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem but cleans up your code: switching your event to simply "input" instead of the entire list.

Comment: Would you want me to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Yeah, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you did not bind enough listeners to capture all input methods for the textbox.

```
.on('keydown keyup keypress change blur focus focusin focusout paste input propertychange', function () {
```

In my experience, difference browsers will have different logic for what triggers these events. This may not be the most elegant solution but it should work.